# Set property to true using Helm

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I am trying to set a label to either true or false:

```
  labels:
    isDevelopment: true
```

But when I try to do that I get a huge parse error.  But if I take the `e` off the end of the true it (kinda) works:

```
  labels:
    isDevelopment: tru
```

I have looked around and found that you can add a `quote` function to it.  I tried that like this:

```
  labels:
    isDevelopment: {{ (quote true) }}
```

That also kind of works, but adds extra quotes around the values in the label:

```
labels:
  isDevelopment: "true"
```

**Is there a way to make it be set with no quotes, but with the full word?**  Like this?

```
labels:
  isDevelopment: true
```

Comment: no, you need to use quotes AFAIK

Comment: Labels are a string to string mapping. During yaml parsing, the parser attempts to identify the type of the value. `true`/`false` are mapped to booleans, causing the parsing error. `"true"`/`"false"` are mapped to strings.